# Need help getting sbt 0.10 to choose a local copy of scala 2.9.1.final on Ubuntu

Tags: scala, sbt

What I have so far:

```
.bashrc
  2 PATH=/opt/scala-2.9.1.final/bin:$PATH
  3 PATH=/opt/sbt:$PATH
```

So my scala-2.9.1.final version is in the /opt folder. The same goes with sbt 0.10.

I'm trying to get it to pick my 2.9.1.final instead of 2.8 whatever. I've tried looking.

What i've done so far is putting symbolic links in projectname/boot/ directory.

```
ln -s /opt/scala-2.9.1.final scala-2.9.1.final
```

But it doesn't seem to work? I've also tried this build.sbt (https://github.com/VonC/xsbt-template/blob/master/build.sbt) and change the version to 2.9.1.final.

How do I get sbt>console to use 2.9.1.final? And how does it build using 2.9.1.final?

This is what I get when I type sbt:

```
user@acomputer:~/project/sbt$ sbt
[info] Set current project to default-295917 (in build file:/home/user/project/sbt/)
>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: curious as to why?  sbt supports 2.9.1 - you just have to put it in your build.

Comment: @andyczerwonka I don't understand the question to why? Why what? I don't exactly know how to just put it in my build? If it does support it I would like to somehow enable it? I am very new at this.

Comment: oh, I see.  I'll add my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not experienced sbt user and may only suggest. Seems sbt 0.10.x use scala 2.8.1 itself, so I think sbt console is working by default with this version.

But you can build project with targetting on 2.9.1 by specify scala version in you build.sbt file: `scalaVersion := "2.9.1"' (see https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Setup "ConfigureBuild")

And also you can switch scala version used by sbt console by typing "`++ 2.9.1`" in sbt prompt. (see https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Running)

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I'm beginning to get how this works now. I had to nuke the project folder and re-initialize sbt and then do ++ 2.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of an build.sbt in one of my projects.

```
organization := "com.andyczerwonka"

name := "esi.intelligence"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

retrieveManaged := false

logLevel := Level.Info

jettyScanDirs := Nil

seq(webSettings :_*)

temporaryWarPath <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile)(_ / "webapp")

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val liftVersion = "2.4-M4"
    Seq(
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile->default",
      "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile",
      "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "7.3.0.v20110203" % "provided,jetty",
      "junit" % "junit" % "4.8" % "test",
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.26",
      "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.6.1" % "test",
      "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-http" % "0.8.5",
      "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.2.138"
    )
  }
```

Notice the 4th line.  This tells sbt that I want to use 2.9.1.  sbt will bring it down for me and use it.